# Custom error_page: Nginx gives 404, PHP sees 200

Tags: nginx, php, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to set up a custom error page. Any error code (400–599) should be routed through this page to display the error and the appropriate status code.

Here's my server configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  mrcsmcln.dev;
    root /Users/mrcsmcln/Sites;
    index index.php index.html;

    error_page 404 /error.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }   
}
```

Next, I have my `error.php`:

```
$status_code = http_response_code();
// do stuff with $status_code here
```

Now, when I point my browser to `mrcsmcln.dev/aoeuidhtns` (which doesn't exist), Nginx reports a 404, but `$status_code` is `200`.

I've tried setting my `error_page` directive to `error_page 404 = /error.php`, but that just makes Nginx think it's a `200`, too!

Why would PHP insist that the status code is `200`, instead of the correct `404`?

Comment: Because you didn't set it to 404?

Comment: And you've asked this question before. The answer is still the same.